Реализовать XOR шифрование для wstring на C++
Требуется алгоритм XOR шифрования для типа wstring C++.
Я пытался выполнить следующий код, но он выдавал неверный результат:
std::wstring XOR(std::wstring text, std::wstring key)
{
    std::wstring decodedText;

    for (int i = 0; i < text.size(); i++)
    {
        decodedText += text[i] ^ key[i % key.size()];
    }

    return decodedText;
}

Буду рад любой помощи.

что именно не работает? выдает не тот текст?

@MS.music9, да, шифрует неправильно

а вы в аргументы wstring передаете, или обычный const char*?

@MS.music9, wstring

Приводите входящую строку, выходящую строку и ожидаемую выходящую строку.

@user7860670 я только что проверял эту функцию, результат и вправду очень странный

@user7860670, к примеру я ввожу строку для шифрования "привет", а ключ "а". Я получаю строку ☼☻♣r. Расшифровывая её, получаю ∌∋≓т

@Kristal4ik в моих тестах, что я ни делал, выводит одну букву. очень странно

@MS.music9, забыл добавить что у меня в функции main() на ввод и вывод установлено следующее _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);

Для редактирования вопроса под ним есть кнопка "Править". Ну и ввод и вывод тут ни к чему. Вставляйте строку в коде и сравнивайте через assert, чтобы проблемы ввода/вывода не подмешивались

Я немного изменил вашу функцию:
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


std::wstring XOR(std::wstring decodedText, std::wstring key){
    for (int i = 0; i < decodedText.size(); i++) {
        #ifdef _DEBUG
          std::wcout << decodedText[i] << "\t" << key[i % key.size()] << "\t" << (decodedText[i] ^ key[i % key.size()]) << std::endl;
        #endif

        decodedText[i] ^= key[i % key.size()];
    }
    
    return decodedText; 
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    const wchar_t* s = L"my text =]";
    const wchar_t* key = L"super key";
    std::wcout << s << std::endl;
    std::wcout << key << "\n\n";
    std::wstring res = XOR(s, key);
    std::wcout << res << std::endl;
    std::wcout << (int)res.size();
}

Судя по размеру выходимой строки, все вроде нормально.
Как вы сказали в комментариях, проблема в кодировке консоли. А я и забыл об этом

Я решил проверить этот код и расшифровать полученный текст. Последние два символа он расшифровал верно, но предыдущие выводит просто квадраты
